# Difference docker repository vs Ubuntu package

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, docker

As of today (2019-03-20), both [the current docker website](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/), and the Ubuntu package have version

> 18.09.2

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50427996/difference-installing-docker-from-ubuntu-repository-and-official-docker-reposito mentions that the Docker repo package might be newer, which is currently not the case.

Are there any reasons to use the Docker repository if you just want a stable install? Are there any differences between these? (Otherwise, it seems easier to avoid another repository, another trusted GPG key etc).

Answer (score 1):

Versions might be the same now but you can expect it to be a game of catch-up

Depending on what docker releases and how complex porting those features are into  Ubuntu ecosystem you will surely end up with a release being older 
at some point using the Ubuntu docker version

*What version you end up using depends on whats best for your needs.*

- Ubuntu: More stable
- Docker: New features faster